# Hard hang, then BSOD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze, bsod

About a month ago, my computer went through a few hard hangs. They each happened when I was watching a video. The first time, it happened around 20 minutes into the video. When I reproduced the problem, it happened in a few seconds. Everything freezes - the video, and any other programs I have open. If I wait maybe 30 seconds later, Windows Explorer crashes and I lose the taskbar. Wait another 30 seconds, and I get a BSOD. It tells me to wait while it creates the error code, but it never does (I guess it freezes again during the blue screen). It also doesn't create a dump file. I've double checked my settings and they're correct, but each time there was no dump.

A few days later, the problems were gone (I have no idea why). But now, a month later, it happened again. 5 minutes into the video, everything froze (I restarted without waiting for the BSOD this time). I looked around and it sounds like the problem could be my hard drive, but I'm not sure how to confirm it.

Comment: Have you updated your video driver lately?

Comment: No. I'll update them and try to reproduce the crash.

Comment: No good, it happened again.

Comment: You will have to debug the memory dump created during bsod, not an easy task.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [an alternative video player](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-media-player/). My experience is that some, such as MPC-HC, can play video files with fewer skips than Windows Media Player (WMP). If one of these can play the file, then WMP may be damaged; attempt to fix it by opening a CMD prompt and entering

> sfc /scannow

See [Microsoft Support for more on System File Checker (SFC)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833).

However, if no player can show that video, but all other videos are OK, then that particular file might be beyond the capability of your video system (e.g. too high resolution), might be truncated or corrupt or might possibly contain malware. Delete it or check that it is not malware and then try it on another PC.

Comment: I was already using MPC-HC. Should I still try using another player?

Comment: Try VLC..http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: It also happened with VLC.

Comment: That seems to confirm an issue with the file... either it is beyond system capabilities or it is malware. (If it were merely corrupt or truncated, it would not cause a *system* crash.).